# Handlebar js how to iterate through json and display as a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js

In my Ruby on Rails application i am using coffee script with handlebar js,

I am getting the json from ENV.tagList in the coffeescript,

the json its like,

```
[{"id":13,"name":"ruby"},{"id":6,"name":"yahoo"},{"id":12,"name":"Mysql"},
{"id":14,"name":"text"},{"id":7,"name":"google"},{"id":8,"name":"Test"},
{"id":3,"name":"normandy"}]
```

In handlebar i want to display each name value as a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The each helper is the item you want to use to accomplish this.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AKIveVA/1/edit

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <button>{{item.name}}</button>
    {{/each}}
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well

```
{{#items}}
  <input type="button" name="{{name}}" value="{{id}}" />
{{/items}}
```